# Wrong Hadoop MaxFileDescriptorCount

Tags: hadoop, operating-system, ubuntu-16.04

Using Ubuntu 16.04 server, I've set max description file to `128000`. The output of the commands

- ulimit -n
- ulimit -Sn
- ulimit -Hn

is `128000`. But in the Hadoop jmx server it is displayed:

```
"MaxFileDescriptorCount" : 4096,
```

Why!?

Comment: Reboot the JVM or OS?

Comment: So many time rebooted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved here in  [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002880/hadoop-jmx-server-display-wrong-file-descriptor)

In case it is `systemd` add `LimitNOFILE=128000` to the `[Service]` section of your `.service` file. Then systemctl daemon-reload to pick up the changes and validate with `systemctl --no-pager show <service> | grep LimitNOFILE`